# Communication between the transport and network layer in kernel

Tags: sockets, networking, linux-kernel

How does a transport layer protocol such as tcp or udp send its data to the IP (network) layer in the kernel. Is this achieved by the use of sockets or any other type of IPC mechanism?

Comment: That is not defined in any standards?  AFAIK, stack developers are free to use any method that works :)  I would probably push a TPDU object reference onto the network layer input queue.

Answer (score 2):

As for data structures used to pass data between the socket and the transport layer it's `struct sk_buff`.

The network subsystem makes it possible to register protocols dynamically. You can use `struct proto` to define your transport layer interface, and `struct proto` for your network layer interface. Finally, `struct net_proto_family` is called when creating a new socket via its `create` function pointer, in which you can attach your protocol to the socket created:

```
static struct net_proto_family myproto_family = {
    .family = PF_MYPROTO,
    .create = myproto_create,
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
};
```

and `myproto_create()` does something like this:

```
struct sock *sk;

/* E.g. if you only support datagrams */
if (sock->type != SOCK_DGRAM)
    return -EPROTOTYPE;

sock->state = SS_UNCONNECTED;
sock->ops = &my_proto_ops;

if ((sk = sk_alloc(net, PF_MYPROTO, gfp_any(), &my_proto)) == NULL)
    return -ENOMEM;

sock_init_data(sock, sk);
```

When your module is initialized:

```
if (proto_register(&my_proto, 1)) {
    printk("failed to register protocol\n");
    return -1;
}

if (sock_register(&my_proto_family)) {
    proto_unregister(&my_proto);
    printk("sock_register() failed\n");
    return -1;
} else {
    printk("socket ops has been registered\n");
}
```